# Number of ways of writing $m=m_1\cdots m_k$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, factoring

I'm currently reading a proof and the very first line starts "We begin by noting that, on using Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact that the number of ways of writing $m=m_1\cdots m_k$ is $O(m^\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have ..." (here, $k\geq1$ is fixed, $m$ and the $m_i$ are positive integers)

Is there some intuition for why the number of ways of writing $m=m_1\cdots m_k$ is $O(m^\varepsilon)$? I can't find a source for this fact and would like to know why it is true. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $m$ is indeed a positive integer and $k\geq1$ is fixed. The $m_i$ are also positive integers

Comment: An idea: Reorder the $m_i$ so that they are decreasing (this adds a constant factor, so doesn't change the asymptotics).  Then $m/m_1 \leq m/2$ and $m/m_1$ has factorization $m_2m_3\cdots m_k\cdot 1$.

Comment: This is sometimes called $d_k(n)$; $d_2(n)$ is the usual divisor function, the number of divisors of $n$. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980226/asymptotics-and-bounds-of-k-divisor-function-d-kn

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892651/divisor-function-asymptotics is related. Deeper questions discussed at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/divisor-function/

Comment: Intuition: The associated Dirichlet series is $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{d_k(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s)^k\,.$$ It converges (absolutely) for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, hence $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} d_k(n) \in O(x^{1 + \varepsilon})$$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. This does **not** prove $d_k(n) \ll n^{\varepsilon}$, it just shows that exceptional values where $d_k(n)$ is large are rare. But it makes $d_k(n) \ll n^{\varepsilon}$ a reasonable expectation. For a proof one can proceed similarly to the $k = 2$ case.